# Enlive - Extract content of tag if attribute has designated value

Tags: clojure, enlive

I am trying use Clojure and Enlive to extract content of `p` html tag under condition that one of attributes has values I designated. Something like this

```
<p itemprop="description"> Some content I want to extract </p>
```

So I want to get `Some content I want to extract` if `itemprop="description"`.

I am very new to Clojure so help would be great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get the text content of any node with the specific attribute, the selector would look something like the following:

```
(require '[net.cgrand.enlive-html :as e])

[(e/attr= :itemprop "description") e/text-node]
```

If the contents contain a mix of text and tags, and you wanted to keep both of them, you should use `net.cgrand.enlive-html/any-node` instead of `net.cgrand.enlive-html/text-node`.

You can test it with the following:

```
(require '[net.cgrand.enlive-html :as e])

(def data "<p itemprop=\"description\"> Some content I want to extract </p>")

(e/select-nodes* (e/html-snippet data)
                 [(e/attr= :itemprop "description") e/text-node])
  ;=> (" Some content I want to extract ")
```